# How Can I Ressurect My Chat History from Google Talk on Droid?

Tags: google-talk, chat-history

I'm chatting someone on my Droid, but when I check the chat history in Google Talk, that chat isn't there. This chat is confined to my phone, but I want to keep a record of it off my phone. Is it saved somewhere in the phone in a log file or something? Can I manually forward that chat to my desktop?  I can't <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> the conversation to my e-mail account, so that's out.  What else?

Comment: Did you perhaps go "off-the-record" with that person?

Comment: For what it's worth, I just chatted someone on my Droid, and the chat is right there under "Chats" in my Gmail account on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Google chat/Talk sessions can be recorded and saved to your Gmail account using a Gmail setting. From Google's [Chat Support](http://support.google.com/chat//bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=29290&rd=1) pages:

> **Changing your chat history settings**
>
> You can adjust your chat history
>   settings in Gmail at any time. Chat history for Google Talk is only
>   available to users who are signed in with a Gmail username.
>
> From Gmail:
>
> - Sign in to Gmail.
> - [Click the gear icon](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/chat)  at the top of any Gmail page, and open the Chat tab.
> - From the Chat tab:
>
>   - Select 'Don't save chat
>       history in my Gmail account' to disable chat history saving, or,
>   - Select 'Save chat history in my Gmail account' to enable chat history
>       saving.
> - Click Save Changes.
>
> Keep in mind that if you've disabled chat
>   history saving, people you chat with may still choose to save chat
>   histories in their Gmail settings. If you would prefer that someone
>   you're talking to doesn't save your chat, you can [take the
>   conversation off the record](http://support.google.com/chat//bin/answer.py?hl=de&answer=29291&rd=1). If you're talking to someone who is
>   connected to the network with a desktop chat client, it's possible
>   that his or her software is keeping a separate copy of the chat
>   history.

Answer (score 0):

While inside the chat if I tap on menu I see an option to *stop to save...* (I don't now the exact text in English.
Maybe you selected that menu?
Or did so the person you are chatting with?